# Is there a second countable topological space, which can not be equipped with a finite borel measure of full support?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

If I have a second countable topological space X, can i Always find a finite borel measure, such that every non-empty open set has positive measure?

without second countability, the discrete topology on $\mathbb R$ is a counter example.

Comment: Yes (if you mean "every *nonempty* open subset"), and actually on any separable topological space. Indeed, assuming $X$ nonempty, consider a dense countable subset with a fully supported discrete probability measure: this defines a measure on all subsets, which is positive on nonempty open subsets.

Comment: Thanks. Of course i meant non-empty.

Comment: perhaps one can ask a similar question, further requiring the measure to have no atoms (assuming no isolated points)?

Comment: @erz if the space has an isolated point won’t that singleton be an atom for any such Borel measure? So then the underlying space should be crowded as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I meant, assuming that $X$ is second countable and without isolated points, can we always find an atomless Borel measure of full support.

Comment: @erz again no: $X$ can be countable with no isolated point, such as $\mathbf{Q}$ with the topology of inclusion into $\mathbf{R}$, so all measures are atomic. So one should at least assume that $X$ has no nonempty countable open subset.

Comment: @YCor perhaps something like a separable connected metric space of infinite cardinality then?

Comment: @erz sure, but connectedness is quite restrictive.

Comment: In this article by Gardner and Gruenhage (http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-04/S0002-9939-1981-0601743-5/S0002-9939-1981-0601743-5.pdf), it is notably proved that it is consistent that every Borel probability measure on a metrizable space of cardinal $\aleph_1$ is atomic (of course this is incompatible with the continuum hypothesis). We can indeed find in $\mathbf{R}$ subsets of cardinal $\aleph_1$ in which every nonempty open subset has cardinal $\aleph_1$ (pick $A\subset\mathbf{R}$ of cardinal $\aleph_1$ and consider $A+\mathbf{Q}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution: if $X$ is second countable, let $D=\{d_n : n =1,2,3,\ldots\}$ be a dense subset of $X$ and define $$\mu(A)= \sum_{n:d_n \in A}\frac{1}{2^n}$$ for all subsets of $X$.

Then clearly $\mu(X)=1$ and $\mu(O)>0$ for all $O$ non-empty and open.

If you want an atomless measure, we need at least that $X$ is crowded, and then we must maybe assume some more on $X$, e.g. to avoid cases like $\mathbb{Q}$ which is second countable and crowded but all of whose measures are atomic by countability of the space.

Comment: So, you used: 2nd countable implies separable to prove a more general result.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I could have sufficed with separable indeed, but the OP asked for second countable.

Answer (score 0):

See Corollary 2.8 in [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102985565) paper:

> If $X$ is perfect, compact and metrizable, then there is a non-atomic regular Borel measure of full support on $X$.

Comment: Reference: Hebert, Lacey, On supports of regular Borel measures, Pacific JM 27(1), 1968.

Comment: Compact metrizable seems awfully strong.  What if $X$ is only Polish and perfect?  It seems like the following would work: take a countable base $U_n$, find a Cantor set $C_n$ inside each $U_n$, and let $\mu_n$ be Cantor measure on $C_n$.  Then let $\mu = \sum 2^{-n} \mu_n$.

Comment: Having lots of Cantor sets inside the space seems enough. As @NateEldredge suggested, one in each open set will get the support property.

Comment: The "compact" assumption can be weakened to countable union of compact subsets, as any $\sigma$-finite measure can be rescaled to a finite measure with the same support.